# Getting "Driver info: driver.version: unknown" while running scripts using protractor

Tags: macos, google-chrome, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am getting below error while executing the scripts in protractor.

```
System info: host: '8888', ip: '88888', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.7', java.version: '14.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[13:13:08] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '****', ip: '****', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.7', java.version: '14.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Can someone please help me here.

Comment: Try this aproach: https://en.it1352.com/article/1236eed0fbb345ee829911d0a2d888aa.html

Answer (score 5):

### Downloading the wrong ChromeDriver due to new m1 chipset

We are downloading the wrong version of ChromeDriver because of the new m1 chipset. There is a fix written https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/pull/478 and I'll have this published to npm this weekend.

### Update: npm published as version 12.1.8

How do you update to webdriver-manager 12.1.8? you could do an `npm install --force protractor`. This should update your dependencies. You could also just clear out your `node_modules/` directory and do a fresh `npm install`

This has been published to npm as version 12.1.8. After updating to version 12.1.8, you might need to run `webdriver-manager clean` before running `webdriver-manager update`.

Comment: When I run `webdriver-manager clean` and `webdriver-manager update` it still get version 12.1.7 downloaded. Tried also `webdriver-manager update 12.1.8` and still got 12.1.7 installed

Comment: `webdriver-manager update 12.1.8` is not an actual command. You should use `npm` to update the node module.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as well, since yesterday.
I also tried reinstalling the OS clean, install only node and chrome. still not working. I assume that's something with chromedriver or new chrome version.

For me, this happens on a mac, latest Catalina patch. On two different linux boxes it works just fine.

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/protractor tmp/qa.conf.js --suite part11
[suite11] 
[suite10] 
[suite10] [10:50:57] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[suite10] [10:50:57] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[suite10] [10:50:57] E/launcher - spawn Unknown system error -86
[suite10] [10:50:57] E/launcher - Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
[suite10]     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
[suite10]     at Object.spawn (child_process.js:553:9)
[suite10]     at exec (/Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js:116:27)
[suite10]     at /Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:219:25
[suite10]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
[suite10] From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
[suite10]     at Function.createSession (/Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
[suite10]     at Function.createSession (/Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
[suite10]     at Direct.getNewDriver (/Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
[suite10]     at Runner.createBrowser (/Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
[suite10]     at /Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29
[suite10]     at _fulfilled (/Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
[suite10]     at /Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
[suite10]     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[suite10]     at /Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
[suite10]     at runSingle (/Users/fabbs/Downloads/app-testing-loginRef2.3-a8697e2393844e5e729e1ad8aa22c097e97e0a82/master/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[suite10] [10:50:57] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```